# How do I include PHP required libs in an AWS EMR streaming cluster

Tags: php, hadoop, amazon-web-services, streaming, emr

I've created a PHP project that converts JSON format into AVRO format.
The original project requires PHP libs that I'm not sure how to add on EMR.

This is the stderr log received by EMR:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or     directory in /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/filecache/12/convert-json-to-avro.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-   dir/usercache/hadoop/filecache/12/convert-json-to-avro.php on line 3
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsUtil).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

And here is the main code for the mapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$outputFile = __DIR__ . '/test_avro_out.avr';
$avroJsonSchema = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/HttpRequestEvent.avsc');
// Open $file_name for writing, using the given writer's schema
$avroWriter = AvroDataIO::open_file($outputFile, 'w', $avroJsonSchema);
$counter = 1;
while (($buf = fgets(STDIN)) !== false) {
    try {
        //replace ,null: with ,"null": to prevent map keys which are not strings.
        $original = array("null:","userIp");
        $replaceWith   = array("\"null\":", "userIP");
        $data = json_decode(str_replace($original, $replaceWith, $buf), true);
        //print_r($buf);
        if ($data === false || $data == null ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unable to parse JSON line");

        }

        $mapped = map_request_event($data);
        var_dump($mapped);

        //$avroWriter->append($mapped);

        //echo json_encode($mapped), "\n";
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        fprintf(STDERR, "Caught exception: %s\n", $ex->getMessage());
        fprintf(STDERR, "Line num: %s\n",$counter);
        fprintf(STDERR, "buf: %s\n", $buf);
    }
    $counter++;
}
$avroWriter->close();
```

Notice I'm using the `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` which states that `autoload.php` is under the folder vendor.

What is the right way to load the vendor folder into the EMR cluster (there are needed files there)?
Should the `require_once` path change?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the bootstrap action which you can add before your job (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#bootstrapCustom)?

Comment: Thanks Guy! That did the trick. tried many other methods but this one worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Guy's comment I've used a bash script similar to the one you can find [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#bootstrapCustom).

I've changed the `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'` line in the code to point to the location where i dropped my files. (`/home/hadoop/contents` worked perfect).
lastly I've added an EMR bootstrap custom step where you can add the bash script so it can run before the PHP streaming step.